# Create tagged vm instance snapshots

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, snapshot

I'm trying to create snapshots of my vm instance on google cloud platform with a custom tag, but it's currently not working as expected. I'm sending the following Post request body to API referring to this documentation [Google docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/disks/createSnapshot)

```
{
    "name":"<SnapshotName>",
    "labels": {
        "<LabelKey>":"<LabelValue>"
    }
}
```

this gives me a positive `200 OK` response, but no label appears.

```
{
 "kind": "compute#operation",
 "id": "<id>",
 "name": "<name>",
 "zone": "<Zone Link>",
 "operationType": "createSnapshot",
 "targetLink": "<Target Link>",
 "targetId": "<Target ID>",
 "status": "PENDING",
 "user": "<User>",
 "progress": 0,
 "insertTime": "<Time>",
 "selfLink": "<Self Link>"
}
```

additionally I tried to use syntax described in "Labeling Resources" documentation [Google Labeling Resources](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/labeling-resources)

```
{
    "name":"<SnapshotName>",
    "labels": [{
        "<Key>":"<LabelKey>"
        "<Value>":"<LabelValue>"
    }]
}
```

this gave me the same result.

In web interface it's possible to create snapshots and label it manually, but I would like to create them with a custom label via API.

Am I doing something wrong, or is it just broken?